# Truncating a table in Supabase/Postgres using JS

Tags: javascript, postgresql, truncate, supabase

I have a table called `events` in Supabase. I'm looking for a way to truncate the table using JavaScript instead of the SQL Editor in Supabase.

I have a function that I call in my js file.

```js
const resetEventTables = async () => {
    const { error } = await supabase.rpc('reset_event_related_tables');
    if (error) console.error(error);
};
```

Running `reset_event_related_tables` executes this function in Supabase:

```sql
TRUNCATE TABLE events RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;
```

But it gives me an error when running the function in js

```js
{
  code: '42501',
  details: null,
  hint: null,
  message: 'must be owner of sequence events_id_seq'
}
```

I can't seem to find the solution somewhere else. And yes, I used the `secret` API key for this when instantiating the `supabase` object.

Comment: Share the contents of the `reset_event_related_tables` function. Likely it needs to be SECURITY DEFINER.

Comment: @SteveChavez function contains only this `TRUNCATE TABLE events RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE`

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY

Comment: @Cif Yeah, we would need the full definition of the function to debug it. Also, I assume this function is just going to be used for your development database, and not the production database, correct?

Comment: @dshukertjr Yes, I just wanted to automate everything in JS, so I could run it easily instead of going to the website to manually do it. Does this pose a security threat tho?

Comment: @Cif Anyone could relatively easily call the database function, so it would not be a good idea to include it in a production app, but for development environment, it should be fine.